# apt-get install python files or just pip install?

Tags: python, numpy, ubuntu, apt-get, apt

I noticed that i was reading a book mentioning to install numpy and opencv by way of apt-get

```
apt-get install python-numpy python-opencv
```

but i can find these in pip by:

```
pip search numpy
```

so this begs me to ask the question:

How do these package managers work?  If i run `pip install numpy` will it install to the same directory as `apt-get install python-numpy`?

I was curious as to what the best way to do it would be if they are installed into different paths.

I want to say "just do it in pip" but its hard to justify since I dont know how each of the different package managers install things.  Are they installed into different directories, but both are on the path to accessible python modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pip` will work on a larger variety of stock systems/OS's, as opposed to `apt-get` which typically applies to Linux flavors. For example, `apt-get` is not available on OS X. You can use Homebrew to get it, but `pip` was the easiest way for me to install OpenCV. Check https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python/3.2.0.7 out. Anything in PyPI should be easier to install.

Comment: OK, so the first thing is that using pip would abstract from OS, allowing you to hit a greater set of machines.  Cool.  im curious what else there would be (specifically where they are installed, etc)

Answer (score -1):

For me the best position is found in https://notes.pault.ag/debian-python/ : if something is required for the system, with apt-get (dpkg), if something is not for the system (maybe development), with pip (and never with sudo to avoid risking to break the system).

Comment: This does not address the more detailed parts of the question: how do they work / where do they install to. Neither does the link as far as I could tell.